# MySQL C# LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having issues handling the LAST_INSERT_ID() from a MySQL insert to my C# app.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

It's a winforms app.  All I want is the `TicketID` of the record that inserts when the save method has finished executing...

Here's my MySQL query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`COMP`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_SaveTicket`(IN AssignedToUserID INT, IN LoggedByUserID INT,
IN LoggedByUserEmailAddress VARCHAR(200), IN LoggedByUserFullname VARCHAR(200), IN DepartmentID INT,
IN QuickCode VARCHAR(255), IN `Subject` VARCHAR(500), IN `Status` VARCHAR(100), IN Priority INT,
IN CreateDate DATE, IN ModifyDate DATE, IN AutoCloseSent INT, IN FirstMessageID INT, IN LastMessageID INT,
IN Info VARCHAR(500), IN NumberOfReplies INT, OUT TicketID INT)
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    INSERT INTO table
    (
        staff, customer_id, customer_email, customer_fullname, departmentid, quickcode
        ,`subject`, `status`, priority, created, updated, auto_close_sent, first_msg_id
        ,last_msg_id, info, replies
    )
    VALUES
    (
        AssignedToUserID, LoggedByUserID, LoggedByUserEmailAddress, LoggedByUserFullname, DepartmentID, QuickCode,
        `Subject`, `Status`, Priority, CreateDate, ModifyDate, AutoCloseSent, FirstMessageID,
        LastMessageID, Info, NumberOfReplies
    );
    SET TicketID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
END
```

Here's my C# method:

```
public async Task SaveTicket(bool connectToLive, string commandText, CommandType commandType, int assignedToUserID,
            int loggedByUserID, string loggedByUserEmailAddress, string loggedByUserFullname, int departmentID, string quickCode, string subject, string status, int priority,
            DateTime createDate, DateTime modifyDate, int autoCloseSent, int firstMessageID, int lastMessageID, string info, int numberOfReplies, [Optional] int ticketID)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    command.CommandType = commandType;

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AssignedToUserID", assignedToUserID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoggedByUserID", loggedByUserID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoggedByUserEmailAddress", loggedByUserEmailAddress);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoggedByUserFullname", loggedByUserFullname);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("QuickCode", quickCode);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DepartmentID", departmentID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Subject", subject);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", status);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Priority", priority);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CreateDate", createDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AutoCloseSent", autoCloseSent);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ModifyDate", modifyDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstMessageID", firstMessageID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastMessageID", lastMessageID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Info", info);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NumberOfReplies", numberOfReplies);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TicketID", ticketID);

                    command.Parameters["TicketID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    switch (connectToLive)
                    {
                        case true:
                            command.CommandText = commandText;

                            command.Connection = connection;

                            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                                connection.Close();
                            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            {
                                connection.Open();
                            }
                            break;
                        case false:
                            command.CommandText = commandText;
                            command.Connection = devConnection;

                            if (devConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                                devConnection.Close();
                            if (devConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            {
                                devConnection.Open();
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    //TEST 1
                    //command.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM table";
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    long id = 0;
                    if (reader != null && reader.Read())
                        id = reader.GetInt64(0);

                    //TEST2
                    //long ticketID = command.LastInsertedId;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "An Error Has Occured", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (devConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        devConnection.Close();

                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's my call to the Save method:

```
logic.SaveTicket(false, "usp_SaveTicket", CommandType.StoredProcedure, 0, GlobalVariables.complaintLoggedByID, GlobalVariables.emailAddress, GlobalVariables.complaintLoggedByValue,
                departmentID, quickCode, txtComplaintSubject.Text, "open", GlobalVariables.priorityID, DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), 0, 0, 0, "", 0);
```

As seen by my `TEST1` and `TEST2` (even though they're commented-out), it doesn't give me the LAST_INSERT_ID().

The initial save will contain zeroes etc. and I need the TicketID to update this record as well as do inserts elsewhere.  Nothing I've tried seems to be working :(

Comment: Did you try to read the value of the parameter TickedID after executing the command?

Comment: I did. If I do I get an exception as the compiler can't implicitly convert from a `MySQLCommand.Parameter` to whatever type I'm converting / casting to.  Performing an explicit conversion also fails :(

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to try and get the value?

Comment: @stuartd, I'm under the impression that setting the TicketID as an output parameter in the query should store the value for me to retrieve it in my C# function?
Please check my `TEST1` and `TEST2` in my SaveTicket method?

Comment: @GrammatonCleric the output Id is stored in the parameter value - `command.Parameters["TicketID"].Value`

Comment: @stuartd when setting a variable to `command.Parameters["TicketID"].Value`, the result is zero

Comment: I would replace the last line from the stored procedure with a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID then, instead of ExecuteNonQuery I would call ExecuteScalar and assign the return value to your local TicketID variable. Of course you don't need anymore an OUT parameter for the TickedID and you don't need the code that follows the ExecuteScalar (the ExecuteReader for LAST_INSERT_ID)

Comment: @Steve You LEGEND! Thanks so much!!  I was driving myself mad...